# Show/hide column in gridview based on Role

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView I populate, and want to show/hide the edit link based on whether the person logged in is either an Admin or User. I am not receiving any errors but cannot figure out why its not working.

**aspx**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="RepView" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#bfbfbf" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="true" CellPadding="2" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="990px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeId" HeaderText="Employee Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Shift" HeaderText="Shift" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Supervisor" HeaderText="Supervisor" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Center" HeaderText="Center" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateSubmitted" HeaderText="Date Entered" />

        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Details">
              <ItemTemplate>                       
                      <a href="/Admin/Details.aspx?AssignmentID=<%# Eval("Id") %>">Edit</a>                     
              </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**code behind**

```
    Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim DefaultConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(DefaultConnection)
       'This is not working...
        If My.User.IsInRole("User") Then
            RepView.Columns(9).Visible = False
        ElseIf My.User.IsInRole("Admin") Then
            RepView.Columns(9).Visible = True
        End If
        ' End of questionable part....

        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT * from Reps")
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            RepView.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            RepView.DataBind()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to put the "questionable part" after define datasource. I think repview resets columns properties after datasource change.

Comment: Thanks but it still shows the edit link when I log in with my test user account.

Comment: Did you check if my.user.IsInRole has value at the time of execution?

Comment: No I didnt, let me try that.

Comment: There is no value in the role.

Comment: You could set visible=false on the link (NOT the column) by default and on rowDatabound set it to true when needed.

Comment: Show this was the problem. user role not set?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code behind "Questionable Part" from the Private Sub BindGrid() to The gridview_Load event. My guess is that what's happening is that the gridview is loading, then it gets to your code Private sub BindGrid() to show/hide columns but the columns are already loaded, therefor it can not hide them. It will continue to show the columns even after running through this code unless you run the check and show/hide the columns in the load event.

One other possible solution is that it looks like in the Private Sub BindGrid() you are trying to hide the columns before the query which means the columns will not have been created yet so you have to create the columns first before you can hide and of them. Move the questionable part down below your sql command.

Try something like this...

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    If x = 0 Then
        GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
    Else
        GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tested this and using x = 0 will hide the first column using x = 1 will show the first column.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Sprayer_Parts_CatalogConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Order#] AS column1, [Gallon], [Price] FROM [Tanks]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66814/discussion-on-answer-by-user3841709-show-hide-column-in-gridview-based-on-role).

Comment: I did not think he had the ability to take part in a chat because he only has a reputation of 3? Does it only matter if one person can chat?

Comment: Typically yes the rep does matter, but since I moved the comments to chat they should be able to join the room.

Comment: Ok I didn't know how else to avoid 30+ comments but this works fine